# Credit Card (saved) payment method

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, payment-methods

I have recently have read that the Credit Card (saved) payment method is not meant to be used on a live site.

What are the reasons for this?

I understand this method stores the credit card number encrypted in the database. Does this violate PCI compliance?

Is there any other reason then security risks?

Comment: If a hackers gets into your site, the key in your local.xml will un-encrypt all your data in the database

Comment: The security risk is obvious. I was curious if there were other reasons.

Comment: The obvious reason **is** the obvious reason... Circular reference that needs no further explanation or elaboration. Magento tells you on their website that CE is not PCI compliant. The database must be on a separate server behind a firewall that locks down access and that's only a start. Anybody who cracks the application server access has instant access to all the card and customer data.

Comment: I was just questioning if there were other reasons. I do not appreciate your rudeness. I understand security is the main risk. I also understand that software can not be PCI compliment. I read through the information and it sounds like a lot of pain to be compliant. As long as I am PCI complaint I can store credit card numbers correct? That is what I am wondering.

Comment: @StevenLynn I think that storing the credit card numbers along with the key to un-encrypt them will make you un-compliant

Comment: @brentwpeterson I will not be storing the encryption key. I will be decrypting the ccNum and then encrypting with my own method.Then storing the ccNum. Is this PCI compliant?

Comment: But is someone got your Local.xml and your database they would be able to de-crypt your CC Numbers. Are you two servers (db +web) dedicated? i.e. not Cloud servers?

Comment: yes two servers will be dedicated. I understand the concept of them being able to decrypt the information if the had the encryption key and access to the database. You can make that argument about most systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason would be security of your customer's information. If anything where to happen with the credit card information you could be held liable.

Being PCI Compliant goes well beyond having an encrypted database. You can find all the information about PCI Compliance  [here](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/merchants/index.php)

Dan

[www.ecommercewebsites.biz](http://www.ecommercewebsites.biz)